# Can't distribute Mac Catalyst extension

Tags: xcode, macos, ios13, mac-catalyst

I successfully uploaded to the Appstore for iOS an app with several extensions, but when I try to upload the same app for Mac AppStore ( a Mac Catalyst App ) I get the following error from Xcode on two extensions

> ERROR ITMS-90355: "Missing Info.plist value. No value for NSExtensionPrincipalClass found in extension Info.plist for MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/MyExtension.appex"

These extensions are a Share Extension and an Action Extension that have a storyboard file, so if I set the NSExtensionPrincipalClass key in the Info.plist file I get the following message in console

> Invalid Configuration: Either NSExtensionMainStoryboard or NSExtensionPrincipalClass must be specified in the extension's Info.plist file but not both.

And of course the extension interface does not appear and nothing works

Anybody got an idea how to solve this?

Alternatively there is the possibility to set only the NSExtensionPrincipalClass key in the Info.plist file and then call the storyboard file programmatically ?

Comment: I'm facing this issue too. Trying to add the key to the Info.plist file didn't fix it.

Comment: @AdamFoot This whole thing is just a torment...
Yesterday I sent a Technical Support Incident, let's see if and what they answer me ...
I'll keep you updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking inspiration from Alessandro Petrolati workaround, I think I found a simpler solution that at least in my case works very well in both extensions.

```
1.  Replace in .plist NSExtensionMainStoryboard with NSExtensionPrincipalClass
2.  Update YourViewController.m file
```

Add this init method to your .m class file

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YournStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
        self = (YourViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourStoryboardID"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

It seems too easy to be true...

The package validation was successful and I finally managed to upload the app to the AppStore Connect without any problems!

All I have to do is to check the latest details before I go live...

Try to believe !

Let me know what your impressions are

Answer (score 0):

Right now Apple has resolved the issue and I was able to load the app with an extension without problems.

[Update: issue not resolved - see comments]

Comment: Thanks Alessandro 
it seemed like great news but I get the same mistake ... 
You changed something in the code? If you want we can also talk about it in Italian ;-)

Comment: After the Apple feedback review I was able to load my app and his extension using Xcode or Transport. It seems everything works as aspected until after few minutes I received an e-mail form the App Store Connect saying: We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "myApp" 1.0 (1). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
ITMS-90355: Missing Info.plist value - No value for NSExtensionPrincipalClass found in extension Info.plist for myApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/myApp_Ext.appex. I've submitted a TSI for technical support now. If you want we talk via e-mail.

Comment: No problem Alessandro, so basically the problem remains... Let's update as soon as someone knows something

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for the Apple answer, I've figure out a workaround consisting to wrap the storyboard to a new AUViewcontroller.

```
1.  include MyXib_Wrapper.h and MyXib_Wrapper.m
2.  Add to AudioUnitInterface.storyboard the ID mainStoryID
3.  Remove or comment the <AUAudioUnitFactory>  from your derived AUViewController class
4.  Update code in MyXib_Wrapper.m -> createAudioUnitWithComponentDescription according to your code (if you are performing more tasks)
5.  Replace in .plist NSExtensionMainStoryboard with NSExtensionPrincipalClass
6.  Sets MyXib_Wrapper for NSExtensionPrincipalClass and factoryFunction (very important!)
```

MyXib_Wrapper.h

```
#import <CoreAudioKit/AUViewController.h>
#import "AudioUnitViewController.h"

@class AudioUnitViewController;

@interface MyXib_Wrapper : AUViewController <AUAudioUnitFactory> {

    AudioUnitViewController *vc;
}
@end
```

MyXib_Wrapper.m

```
#import "MyXib_Wrapper.h"
#import "AudioUnitViewController.h"
#import "MyAudioUnit.h"

@implementation MyXib_Wrapper

- (MyAudioUnit *) createAudioUnitWithComponentDescription:(AudioComponentDescription) desc error:(NSError **)error {
    vc.audioUnit = [[MyAudioUnit alloc] initWithComponentDescription:desc error:error];

    // perform here more tasks    
    return vc.audioUnit;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AudioUnitInterface" bundle:nil];
        vc = (AudioUnitViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainStoryID"];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
-(UIView*)view {
    return vc.view;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.preferredContentSize = vc.preferredContentSize;
}
@end
```

Comment: We cross our fingers waiting for Apple's answer...
In the meantime I have also updated macOS to version 10.15.4 just released and Xcode to version 11.4 in the hope that something will change ...
And instead nothing, always the same mistake ...

Comment: Ragazzetto, I've experimented before what you propose but I’ve discarder this solution since this approch will allocate a twice ‘YourViewController’. This occur since the class is before instantiated by the info.plist ‘factoryFunction’ key and then by the NSExtensionPrincipalClass which trigger the initWithNibName. Thus the assignation ‘self = (YourViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourStoryboardID”];’ will trigger before the 'dealloc' func.
And consequentially the ‘initWithNibName’ again.
This is redundant and could provide unspected behaviours.

Comment: Surely it will not be the perfect approach, but in my case of two very simple extensions it behaves perfectly.
Thanks for the explanation Alessandro !

Answer (score 0):

my approach is to just use a trivial VC loaded in code, then VC containment to actually present the VC we want (loaded from Storyboard)

info.plist contains:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).PreviewVCLoader</string>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>QLSupportsSearchableItems</key>
        <true/>
        <key>QLSupportedContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.hobbyistsoftware.jump</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.quicklook.preview</string>
</dict>
```

and then my PreviewVCLoader class is

```
import UIKit
import QuickLook

class PreviewVCLoader: UIViewController, QLPreviewingController {

    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    
    lazy var realVC:PreviewViewController = {
        let board = UIStoryboard.init(name: "MainInterface", bundle: nil)
        guard let vc = board.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreviewViewController") as? PreviewViewController else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate storyboard in preview")
        }
        return vc
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

        self.addChild(realVC)
        realVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        realVC.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(realVC.view)
        realVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    func preparePreviewOfFile(at url: URL, completionHandler handler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        realVC.preparePreviewOfFile(at: url, completionHandler: handler)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my extension I'm using the storyboard, it would be possible to use
NSExtensionPrincipalClass instead of NSExtensionMainStoryboard ?
Meanwhile, I've sent a feedback to Apple,