# Extension is not available when building for Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, xcode, mac-catalyst

Currently I have an iOS app that I am trying to build for Mac Catalyst, unfortunately when building I get the following error for some of my different targets:

> Building for Mac Catalyst, but the embedded app extension
>   'ShareExtension.appex' is building for iOS. You may need to configure
>   'ShareExtension.appex' to build for Mac Catalyst or restrict the
>   platforms for which this app extension should be embedded in the
>   target editor.

How do I disable the share extension when MacOS is the platform I'm building for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to go to your **main** app's:

> Target > General > Frameworks, Libraries & Embedded Contant

Then for the following extensions that aren't supported, select the Platforms as only `iOS` or `MacOS`, it should look like the following:

Make sure to **Clean & Rebuild** when done!

[image]

Comment: Hi. I'm at the beginning of the process of adding a Share Extension to my Catalyst app, and while doing some research I came across to both your answer, which makes me think a single extension will work on iOS and macOS, and to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59765108/cant-distribute-mac-catalyst-extension) where a couple of users are encountering issues when uploading the finished product to the App Store. Did you successfully ship a Share Extension using Catalyst to the Store? Thank you!

Comment: @cdf1982 no we weren't able to, but it was because of different reasons (due Google Firebase), however this was able to bypass the error we had with Catalyst.

Comment: For reference, adding a new iOS extension to an already iOS+macOS app in Xcode 11.5 already set the platforms of the extension as recommended in this answer for me.

Comment: @Asleepace in the "Frameworks, Libraries & Embedded Content" tab I do not see the column "Platforms". It is simply not there.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to go to the target settings of the extension that causes trouble, and setting "Supported Platforms" to the correct platform(s).

The issue was that these settings were taken from the projects default settings which included a platform that was not supported for the extension.